# The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this operation in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, scriptblock, powershell-sdk

I am having below method which is being called for different PS scripts and I would like the PowerShell object to be created only once and for that I made the Powershell object as static(see below code). but then it gives me error

> The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this
> operation.

How should I handle this? what is the best way to optimize my below code?
NB: Below code works fine if I remove static.

```
class DataRulesPSScripts
    {
        static PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        public IEnumerable<object> RunScriptBlock( ScriptBlock scriptBlock, Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters )
        {
            var vars = scriptParameters.Select( p => new PSVariable( p.Key, p.Value ) ).ToList();
            return scriptBlock.InvokeWithContext( null, vars );
        }

        public async Task<ScriptBlock> CreateScriptBlock( string pSScript )
        {            
            ps.AddScript( pSScript );
            var scriptBlock = (await ps.InvokeAsync())[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
            return scriptBlock;
        }
    }
}
```

this is called from here :

```
internal async Task<string> GeneratePartitionKey( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg)
        {       
            var result =await GenerateKeys(arg);
            return result[0].ToString();
        }        

        internal async Task<string> GenerateRowKey( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg )
        {
            var result = await GenerateKeys( arg );
            return result[1].ToString();
        }

        private async Task<List<object>> GenerateKeys( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg )
        {
            var pars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            pars.Add( "_", arg );
            DataRulesPSScripts ds = new DataRulesPSScripts();
            var scriptBlock = await ds.CreateScriptBlock( PSScript );
            var results = ds.RunScriptBlock( scriptBlock, pars ).ToList();
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: What's the value of `PSScript`?

Comment: its a powershell script let say {$_.Name,$_.code}.. these are present in Dictionary arg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no reason to create and interact with `ScriptBlock` instances directly in your C# code - they are used *internally* by the PowerShell SDK**:<sup>[1]</sup> They are internally created and stored when you pass a piece of PowerShell code as a *string* to the [`PowerShell.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript) method, and are invoked via the *`PowerShell` instance's*, [`.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke) method.

While **your *indirect* way of obtaining a script block for *direct execution in C# code*** by letting a `PowerShell` instance create and output it for you via an `.AddScript()` call (`ps.AddScript( pSScript ); var scriptBlock = (await ps.InvokeAsync())[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;`) *does* give you a script block that you can call directly from C# code via its `.Invoke()` method (if you created the script block directly in C# code, you wouldn't be able to invoke it all, due to not being connected to a PowerShell *runspace*), **such calls only provide *success* output** - **output from all other [PowerShell streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) would be *lost*** - that is, the originating `PowerShell` instance's `.Streams` property wouldn't reflect such output, which notably makes non-terminating *errors* that occurred inaccessible, and, similarly, the `.HadErrors` property would not reflect whether non-terminating errors occurred. Therefore, this approach **should be avoided**.<sup>[2]</sup>

Here's an example that **creates a script bock *implicitly, behind the scenes***, via [`PowerShell.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript), **passes an argument to it** and invokes it:

```cs
// Define the script-block text.
// It expects a single argument that is an object with .Name and .Code
// properties, whose values are echoed.
// NOTE: Do NOT include { ... }
var scriptBlockText = "$obj = $args[0]; $obj.Name; $obj.Code";

// Define an object to pass to the script block.
var obj = new { Name = "Abc", Code = 42 };

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
  
  // Add the script block and an argument to pass to it.
  ps
    .AddScript(scriptBlockText)
    .AddArgument(obj);

  // Invoke and echo the results.  
  foreach (var o in ps.Invoke()) {
    Console.WriteLine(o);
  }

}
```

However, **the above isn't *reusable*, because once you've added arguments or parameters with `.AddParameter(s)` or `.AddArgument()`, you cannot remove them and specify different ones** to perform another call - as far as I know.

- [GitHub issue #15004](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15004#issuecomment-799653120) contains a relevant discussion.

The workaround is to **use PowerShell *pipeline input*** (as provided via the optional `input` parameter you can pass to [`PowerShell.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke), as that **enables repeated invocations with different input.**
However, your script block must then be constructed accordingly:

```cs
// Define the script-block text.
// This time, expect the input to come via the *pipeline*, which
// can be accessed via the $input enumerator.
// NOTE: Do NOT include { ... }
var scriptBlockText = "$obj = $($input); $obj.Name; $obj.Code";

// Define two objects to pass to the script block, one each in 
// two separate invocations:
object[] objects = {
  new { Name = "Abc", Code = 42 },
  new { Name = "Def", Code = 43 }
};

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
  
  // Add the script block.
  ps.AddScript(scriptBlockText);

  // Perform two separate invocations.
  foreach (var obj in objects) {

    // For housekeeping, clean the previous non-success streams.
    ps.Streams.ClearStreams();

    // Invoke the script block with the object at hand and echo the results.
    // Note: The input argument must be an enumerable, so we wrap the object
    //       in an aux. array.
    foreach (var o in ps.Invoke(new[] { obj })) {
      Console.WriteLine(o);
    }

  }

}
```

---

Alternatively, if feasible, **consider making do *without* script blocks**, as they require parsing (albeit as one-time overhead in this case) and - on Windows - are subject to the effective [*execution policy*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies), which could prevent their execution (though you can bypass such a restriction on a per-process basis, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67994020/45375)).

Without script blocks, you'd have to invoke one or more commands individually, using [`PowerShell.AddCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddCommand) calls, separating multiple independent commands with [`PowerShell.AddStatement()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddStatement).

- If a single command or a pipeline of command accepts all input *via the pipeline*, you can use the same approach as above.
- Otherwise - if `.AddParameter(s)` / `.AddArgument()` are needed - you'd have to call `ps.Commands.Clear()` and *re-add the commands before every (repeat) invocation*; however, compared to calling `.AddScript()`, this should introduce little overhead.

---

**Adaptation of the reusable technique to your code**:

Class `DataRulesPSScripts`, which uses a static `PowerShell` instance
and adds the script block once, in its static constructor.

- Note: Consider using an *instance* property instead and making the class implement `IDisposable` to allow users of the class control over the PowerShell instance's lifecycle.

```
class DataRulesPSScripts
{
  static PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
  // The script-block text:
  // Note that $ParamA and $ParamB must correspond to the keys of the
  // dictionary passed to the script block on invocation via .InvokeAsync()
  static string PSScript = @"$argDict = $($input); & { param($ParamA, $ParamB) [pscustomobject] @{ Partition = $ParamA; Key = 1 }, [pscustomobject] @{ Row = $ParamB; Key = 2 } } @argDict";

  static DataRulesPSScripts() {
    // Add the script-block text only once, which therefore incurs the
    // overhead of parsing the text into a script block only once,
    // and allows repeated later invocations via .Invoke() with pipeline input.
    ps.AddScript(PSScript);
  }
  public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> RunScriptBlock(Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> scriptParameters)
  {
    // Pass the parameter dictionary as pipeline input.
    // Note: Since dictionaries are enumerable themselves, an aux. array
    //       is needed to pass the dictionary as a single object.
    return await ps.InvokeAsync<object>(new [] { scriptParameters });
  }

}
```

The code that uses the class, which passes the parameters via *the pipeline*:

```
internal async Task<string> GeneratePartitionKey(Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg)
{
  var result = await GenerateKeys(arg);
  return result[0].ToString();
}

internal async Task<string> GenerateRowKey(Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg)
{
  var result = await GenerateKeys(arg);
  return result[1].ToString();
}


private async Task<List<object>> GenerateKeys(Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> args)
{
  DataRulesPSScripts ds = new DataRulesPSScripts();
  var results = await ds.RunScriptBlock(args);
  return results.ToList();
}
```

Sample call (`obj` is the object that contains the methods above; assumes a simplified `EntityProperty` class with property `.Value`):

```
Console.WriteLine(
  obj.GenerateRowKey(
    new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> { ["ParamA"] = new EntityProperty { Value = "bar" },  ["ParamB"] = new EntityProperty { Value = "baz" } }
  ).Result
);
```

The above should yield something like:

```
@{Row=demo.EntityProperty; Key=2}
```

This is the string representation of the 2nd custom object output by the script block.

---

<sup>[1] In *PowerShell script code*, by contrast, `ScriptBlock` instances *are* used directly, typically in the form of [script-block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) *literals* (`{ ... }`), invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).</sup>

<sup>[2] Here's a quick demonstration from PowerShell:

`$ps=[PowerShell]::Create(); $sb = $ps.AddScript("{ 'hi'; Get-Item nosuchfile }").Invoke()[0]; "call result: $($sb.Invoke())"; "had errors: $($ps.HadErrors)"; "error stream: $($ps.Streams.Error)"`

Even though the call produced a non-terminating error, `.HadErrors` reports `$false`, and the `.Streams.Error` is empty.</sup>